# Symfony : run project from ftp to localhost

Tags: symfony, ftp, composer-php

After downloading the source files from ftp of a symfony project to work on, I want to know what is the version o the project? When I didn't found the exact location to run composer!

here is the Tree of the project :

```
> https://pastebin.com/EkRcpppw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't have access to the console (`app/console --version` or `bin/console --version` for Symfony3 ), you could try reading `/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKe‌​rnel/Kernel.php`, where the version is hardcoded.

In exemple:

```
const VERSION         = '3.2.0';
```

would means that you have the version 3.2.0 of the Symfony Framework.